# Writing text to txt file in python on new lines?

Tags: python, file

So I am trying to check whether a url exists and if it does I would like to write the url to a file using python. I would also like each url to be on its own line within the file. Here is the code I already have:

```
import urllib2
```

CREATE A BLANK TXT FILE THE DESKTOP

```
urlhere = "http://www.google.com"   
print "for url: " + urlhere + ":"  

try: 
    fileHandle = urllib2.urlopen(urlhere)
    data = fileHandle.read()
    fileHandle.close()
    print "It exists"
```

Then, If the URL does exist, write the url on a new line in the text file

```
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print 'PAGE 404: It Doesnt Exist', e
```

If the URL doesn't exist, don't write anything to the file.

---

Comment: So... what was the question again?

Comment: I want to be able to enter any url to 'urlhere', have the program test whether or not it exists or is a 404 page and then write only the url's that I try that exist to a txt file that is on the desktop.

Comment: At the moment, I have the url checking in place, all I need to do is have program the url being written to a txt file.

Comment: That's not a question.

Comment: Okay, How do I use python to edit text files?

Comment: What do you mean "each url"? You only have one URL to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you worded your question is a bit confusing but if I understand you correctly all your trying to do is test if a url is valid using urllib2 and if it is write the url to a file? If that is correct the following should work.

```
import urllib2
f = open("url_file.txt","a+")
urlhere = "http://www.google.com"   
print "for url: " + urlhere + ":"  

try: 
    fileHandle = urllib2.urlopen(urlhere)
    data = fileHandle.read()
    fileHandle.close()
    f.write(urlhere + "\n")
    f.close()
    print "It exists"

except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print 'PAGE 404: It Doesnt Exist', e
```

If you want to test multiple urls but don't want to edit the the python script you could use the following script by typing `python python_script.py "http://url_here.com"`. This is made possible by using the sys module where sys.argv[1] is equal to the first argument passed to python_script.py. Which in this example is the url ('http://url_here.com').

```
import urllib2,sys
f = open("url_file.txt","a+")
urlhere = sys.argv[1]   
print "for url: " + urlhere + ":"  

try: 
    fileHandle = urllib2.urlopen(urlhere)
    data = fileHandle.read()
    fileHandle.close()
    f.write(urlhere+ "\n")
    f.close()
    print "It exists"

except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print 'PAGE 404: It Doesnt Exist', e
```

Or if you really wanted to make your job easy you could use the following script by typing the following into the command line `python python_script http://url1.com,http://url2.com` where all the urls you wish to test are separated by commas with no spaces.

```
import urllib2,sys
f = open("url_file.txt","a+")
urlhere_list = sys.argv[1].split(",")   

for urls in urlhere_list:
    print "for url: " + urls + ":" 
    try: 
        fileHandle = urllib2.urlopen(urls)
        data = fileHandle.read()
        fileHandle.close()
        f.write(urls+ "\n")

        print "It exists"

    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print 'PAGE 404: It Doesnt Exist', e
    except:
        print "invalid url"
f.close()
```

`sys.argv[1].split()` can also be replaced by a python list within the script if you don't want to use the command line functionality. Hope this is of some use to you and good luck with your program.

**note**
The scripts using command line inputs were tested on the ubuntu linux, so if you are using windows or another operating system I can't guarantee that it will work with the instructions given but it should.

Comment: Smashed it! Thanks a lot man! This really helps! I appreciate the extra effort you went into with the bottom 2!!

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help you out! It also gives me some much desired practice so I should partially be thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
import urllib2

url  = 'http://www.google.com'
data = ''

try:
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    data = 'PAGE 404: It Doesnt Exist ' + e

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as out_file:
   out_file.write(data)
```

Comment: Hey man! 
Close, but that writes out a lot of random stuff to the outfile.txt. All I want is it to write a url that worked to the outfile.txt. 
 
And everytime I run the program, Instead of re-creating the outfile, it just modifies the existing file by starting on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests

def url_checker(urls):
    with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as f:
       for url in urls:
           r = requests.get(url)
           if r.status_code == 200:
              f.write('{0}\n'.format(url))

url_checker(['http://www.google.com','http://example.com'])
```